# Query notation for the sitecore 'source' field in template builder

Tags: c#, asp.net, content-management-system, sitecore, sitecore6

I am trying to set the the source field of a template using the query notation (or xpath - whichever works), but none of them seems to be working.

My content tree is a multisite content tree:

```
France
--Page 1
----Page1A
-------Page1AA
--Page 2
--Page 3
--METADATA
----Regions

US
--Page 1
----Page1A
-------Page1AA
--Page 2
--Page 3
--METADATA
----Regions
```

Each site has its own METADATA folder, and I want it so that when adding a page inside each of the main country nodes, I want the values to reflect whatever is in the METADATA of that site. I have two different fields for now - a droplink and a treelistex field. So I thought I can just get the parent item that is a country site, and get the metadata folder for that. When I put the following query in both the fields, I get different results:

```
 query:./ancestor::*[@@templatename='CountryHome']/METADATA/Regions/*
```

- For the droplink field, I get only the first Region (one item)
- For the treelistex field, I get the entire content tree

I then tried to modify the query a little bit and took the 'query' notation out

```
 ./ancestor::*[@@templatename='CountryHome']/METADATA/Regions/*
```

If I go to the developer center/xpath builder, and set the context node to any item underneath the main country site, it returns me exactly what I need, but when I put this in the source, I get the entire content tree in both the cases.

Help!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What you have here should work with the Droplink field. Perhaps you are referring to Droptree?

```
query:./ancestor::*[@@templatename='CountryHome']/METADATA/Regions/*
```

As for the TreelistEx, I don't think the default Treelist fields support Sitecore query. However, [this article](http://sdn.sitecore.net/Scrapbook/Custom%20TreeList%20that%20supports%20query.aspx) describes how to create a custom TreeList that supports it.

Comment: ahh yes, I have a droptree, not droplink. That sucks though - the manuals all say that any fields with 'source' field should work. So this doesn't work on droptree?

Comment: I found the different fields support different variations of the query syntax. It seems they have been developed completely independently. Best is to submit a ticket with sitecore.

Answer (score 46):

## Fields that support Sitecore Query

Where you can use the syntax `query:` or `fast:` (for FastQuery):

- Droplist
- Grouped Droplist
- DropLink
- Grouped Droplink
- Checklist
- Multilist
- Droptree

## Fields that support Parameterized Datasource

Where you can use enhanced syntax with Parameterized datasource
query:

- Droptree †
- Treelist
- TreelistEx

† *Droptree only supports the `Datasource` and `DatabaseName` parameters.*

#### The enhanced query string syntax includes the following parameters:

- Datasource
- DatabaseName
- AllowMultipleSelection
- IncludeItemsForDisplay
- ExcludeItemsForDisplay
- IncludeTemplatesForSelection
- ExcludeTemplatesForSelection
- IncludeTemplatesForDisplay
- ExcludeTemplatesForDisplay

These are used like this: `Datasource=/sitecore/content/home/Products/&IncludeTemplatesForDisplay=Product Category&ExcludeTemplatesForSelection=Product Description&IncludeTemplatesForSelection=Product Category`

Mark Ursino has a great post on how to use this kind of syntax [here](http://firebreaksice.com/tame-your-sitecore-treelists/).

Comment: Thanks for the response! In the end, I made the custom field that supports xpath, and used that. But this is definitely useful for simpler queries..

Comment: BTW - that blog you posted the link to is Mark Ursino's blog :) Brian Pederson's blog is very informative as well..

Comment: The exclude parameters don't seem to work on `Droptree` but they do in `Treelist`. Ugh!

Comment: SDN says only `TreeList` and `TreeListEx` support parameterized data source. Making `Droptree` officially totally useless.

Comment: As of SC 6.6 Droptree accepts a SC query with the query: format.  Just confirmed in a project I'm working on.