# Sitecore DropList with datasource in asp drop down list

Tags: c#, .net, sitecore

I am making a form in Sitecore which data sources drop down items.

In a nutshell, I have a data template which has a DropList field which I want to then data source from a Sitecore folder item which contains numerous items of a different data template.

For example - a 'Categories' drop down list, in which the content editor can define their own categories by creating new items of the 'category' template type.

I then want to populate an drop down list with these values.

What is the best way to go about populating a drop down list using this method? I have a number of drop downs to populate like this in my form so want to nail down the best method and I haven't found any examples of something similar after an hour or 2 of browsing the web.

Comment: The droplist is where, in Sitecore admin or frontend code presented to the user?

Comment: So front end, users see a drop-down list, but this is all saving to the database on submit so it also will be in the DropList as options for entry via the backend if required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use query and look for template name or other value you require or add parameters to the DataSource as shown [here](http://firebreaksice.com/tame-your-sitecore-treelists/)

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12611258/query-notation-for-the-sitecore-source-field-in-template-builder) answer for some examples