# Multi sites Application : Relative Data source

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7

Its about multi sites Application . I have multiple folder in sitecore content tree . Each folder is having local folder structure Example : A -> X,Y,Z , B -> X,Y,Z , C->X,Y,Z.

Here i m using same template for A, B , C . And want to set standard values for presentation detail .

But I am facing one issue . How to give common data source for rendering X, Y ,Z Item in standard values.
Is there any option to give relative path as data source . Or i have to write pipeline for this .

Please Help

Comment: Do you want to edit the sublayout datasource ? If yes - you can take a look at - https://www.sitecore.net/Learn/Blogs/Technical-Blogs/Sitecore-7-Development-Team/Posts/2013/04/Sitecore-7-Datasources.aspx Otherwise please clarify what exactly you need.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to create a relative datasource by submitting a query in the datasource field.
Example: 'query:./X'

Check out:
http://www.seanholmesby.com/multiple-datasource-locations-using-queries-are-back-in-sitecore-7-2-update-2/
[Query notation for the sitecore 'source' field in template builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12611258/query-notation-for-the-sitecore-source-field-in-template-builder)

Comment: To reiterate, the important piece of the above is the `./` prefix. This tells Sitecore to start at the current location (rather than the root node).