# Using Sitecore query in Field 'source' not working properly

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7

I am using a sitecore query in a source for a field `Subsidiary`:

```
/sitecore/content/Home/Organization/descendant::*[@@templateid='{8BE84E6C-CAA3-4D03-9FD2-B95B89A7DDE0}']
```

Field Type is : `Droplist`

So in When I see the item which is based on the above template and I click on the field, I don't see any thing.

You can also see the images for more detail.

This is `template` where I am giving the above `query` in the `source`.
[image]

This is what I see on the `item` in the field `Subsidiary`

[image]

Comment: The source field on the template will not show the outcome of the query. An Item based on that template will show the outcome of the query

Comment: @jRobbins yes. I know this. the item that is based on this template will show 0 result in the droplist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to prefix your xpath with `query:`

`query:/sitecore/content/Home/Organization/descendant::*[@@templateid='{8BE84E6C-CAA3-4D03-9FD2-B95B89A7DDE0}']`

You can also use the shorthand for `descendant::`:

`query:/sitecore/content/Home/Organization//*[@@templateid='{8BE84E6C-CAA3-4D03-9FD2-B95B89A7DDE0}']`

Comment: thanks a lot!! I have spend more than 3 hours to figure out the problem ;( and it was only this small text query:/

Comment: @Kami See this post for info on which type may need the prefix: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12617948/661447