# Sitecore Multilist dynamic website source property

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore-mvc

My Sitecore Content Editor has the following structure:

```
- Sitecore
  - Content
     - Brand Websites
         - WebsiteOne
             - Website - UK
                 - Pages
                     - Home
         - WebsiteTwo
             - ...
         - WebsiteThree
             - ...
```

I am trying to create a multilist that will allow editors to select pages to be displayed in the footer.

I want to allow the Source field of this multilist to be dynamic for the site that the editor is on (WebsiteOne/Two/Three).

I have been exploring the XPath Builder however i am not sure about the dynamic website name part.

Ideally what i want is something like:

```
./query:/sitecore/content/Brand Websites/[@@name]/Website - UK/Pages/*
```

Is this possible to dynamically pass the current website into this query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will find your answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12611258/query-notation-for-the-sitecore-source-field-in-template-builder).

Comes down to something like this:

`query:./ancestor::*[@@templatename='WebsiteHomeTemplateName']/Pages/*`

Comment: Thanks for that, do you know where I would define WebsiteHomeTemplateName ?

Comment: It is the name of the template you used to create the home nodes of the website, so the items "WebsiteOne", "WebsiteTwo", ...  So don't use 'WebsiteHomeTemplateName', use the real template name (which I cant know so I used this). This assumes the home nodes have used the same template.