# Setting specific items on Sitecore TreeviewEx

Tags: xml, dialog, sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore-mvc

I'm working on creating a new feature on the Content Editor with specific templates. I'm trying to create something similar to the General Links' "insert link" and "media link", but the tree that is shown will only contain the items with a specific template.

Just to be more clear, I'll show a sample tree.

[image]

This is how the normal TreeviewEx will show up on the dialog, but I want it to show only the items with a specific template. Is there a way to do this? or maybe an alternative way something like using combobox?

The XML control I used is just something like this

```
<Scrollbox Width="100%" Height="100%" Background="white" Border="none" Padding="0">
  <TreeviewEx ID="InternalLinkTreeview" DataContext="InternalLinkDataContext" Root="true" />
</Scrollbox>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the `TreelistEx` field type (assume you mean this and not TreeviewEx since that is not a valid default Sitecore field) then you can use an enhanced parameterized datasource syntax in the `Source` of the field in your template to set which templates should be displayed and which templates should be seletable.

You want to set a root item path using the `DataSource` parameter, and then use a combination of `IncludeTemplatesForDisplay / ExcludeItemsForDisplay` to only show certain items of particular templates and `IncludeTemplatesForSelection` to only allow selection of specific item templates in the `TreelistEx` field. For example:

`Datasource=/sitecore/content/TUSM/home/&IncludeTemplatesForDisplay=Landing1,Landing2,Landing3&IncludeTemplatesForSelection=Offices`

You may want to combine that with an Xpath query if you need to limit the scope to single sites (e.g. `query:./ancestor-or-self::*[@@templatename='Site']/Home`) but there are other ways of achieving a similar. Depending on whether you require multiple items to be selected then you may wish to consider `Droptree` for single item selection. Or maybe you wish to use just an rerlative xpath query with template restriction if you want to "locally" scope the selection (instead of allow selection from `/sitecore/content`)

You can read more in [this blog post](https://getfishtank.ca/blog/treelist-data-source-hidden-functionality) and [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12617948/661447).